# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() In BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need your help to resolve this problem :

```
Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
```

I'm using a **BroadcastReceiver** to start the notification service :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WakeLock.acquire(context);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, new Intent(context, StartNotificationService.class).putExtras(intent));
    } else {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, StartNotificationService.class).putExtras(intent));
    }
}
```

Have you any idea please ? How can I resolve this issue ?
Thanks you

Comment: You have to call `startForeground` from within the foreground service. This was added I believe in Oreo (not too sure). You have a time window to do this. If you don't call it from within that time, Android throws that exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Service` must call `startForeground()` when it is started, otherwise the system will not allow it to run.